# How to use NGINX to forward a dynamic PORT given in the URL

Tags: nginx

I have a server with IP `xxx.yyy.zzz`, and domain I purchased dummy.de. I am trying to make a reverse proxy and the current nginx config file is working perfectly fine but I want to proxy pass the URL this time with a dynamic port.

For example, if I want to reach `dummy.com:20000` to be forwarded like `xxx.yyy.zzz:20000`.
But everything is dynamic in terms of port.

How can I update the config, to work as mentioned above?

```
server {
    server_name dummy.com;

    location / {

        # Construct the proxy_pass URL using the extracted port number
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dummy.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```